# Using Django ORM to retrieve recent rows

Tags: django, django-orm

In SQL, if I wanted to query a table for data from the most recent 10 minutes (regardless of timezones and such), I'd simply do (using postgresql parlance):

```
select * from table where creation_time > now() - interval'10 mins';
```

Is there an equivalent way to do something like this using the Django ORM, disregarding what timezone settings one has set for the app? Would be great to get an illustrative example here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:-

Data within 10 minutes :-

```
from datetime import datetime, timedelta

time_threshold = datetime.now() - timedelta(minutes=10)
results = Table.objects.filter(createdOn__lte=time_threshold)
```

Last 10 rows based on `createdOn` value:-

```
recentData = Table.objects.all().order_by('-createdOn')[:10]
```

Last 10 rows if you don't have `createdOn` column to filter:-

```
recentData = Table.objects.all().order_by('-id')[:10]
```

Comment: Clarification: should it be `datetime.now()` or `datetime.utcnow()`. In my particular scenario, would it ever make sense to have `datetime.utcnow()`?

Comment: Not not really because `datetime.utcnow()` OS provided values.